# Hibernate foreign key always inserted as NULL

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am facing issue in below hibernate entity's. 
While inserting record into base table the foreign key is always inserted as NULLin child table. 
Please help, did i miss configure any Notation here ?.

```
    //PK
    @Entity
    @Table(name="s_c_bur_dtl")
    public class SurveyConductBurglaryDetails {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator="surveycondbgdtl_seq")
        @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="surveycondbgdtl_seq",sequenceName="surveycondbgdtl_seq",allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
        @Column(name = "nsurveycondbgdtlcd", unique=true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint")
        private BigInteger surveyCondBgDtlCd;


        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy="surveyConductBurglaryDetails")
        private List<SurveyConductBurglaryProperty> surveyConductBurglaryProperties;

    }

    //FK
    @Entity
    @Table(name="s_c_bur_property")
    public class SurveyConductBurglaryProperty {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator="surveycondbgproperty_seq")
        @javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator(name="surveycondbgproperty_seq",sequenceName="surveycondbgproperty_seq",allocationSize=1,initialValue=1)
        @Column(name = "nsurveycondbgpropertycd", unique=true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "bigint")
        private BigInteger surveyCondBgPropertyCd;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "nsurveycondbgdtlcd")        
        private SurveyConductBurglaryDetails surveyConductBurglaryDetails;

    }   

 @Service
    class SaveService{
     @Autowired DbService dbService;

    public void conductSurvey(SurveyConductBurglaryDetails surveyConductBurglaryDetails) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException{

        dbService.saveOrUpdate(surveyConductBurglaryDetails); // call for save

    }
    }

    @Service
    class DbService{
    public void saveOrUpdate(Object insertObj){

            Session session = surveyTransactionManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            Transaction transaction = session.getTransaction();
            if(!transaction.isActive()){
                session.beginTransaction();
            }

            try{
                session.saveOrUpdate(insertObj);
                transaction.commit();

            }catch(Exception e){

                transaction.rollback();
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
                    logger.debug("SurveyDBService.saveOrUpdate Catch block");
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{

            }


        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Please, add save entites code.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i have shared the save code as well now.

Comment: What do you mean by "inserted as null"? Is it null after the transaction is complete? Or is it null when it is `insert`-ed into the database (because Hibernate does this, inserts rows with null values in the foreign keys, then does an `update` on the row..)

Comment: Btw your table names looks like they've been written by the devil himself. You should aim for something a human being can understand..

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide full code. So I can make an assumption. You don't set `SurveyConductBurglaryDetails` to `SurveyConductBurglaryProperty`. Your code should looks like this:

```
SurveyConductBurglaryDetails details = new SurveyConductBurglaryDetails();
details.setSurveyConductBurglaryProperties(
    new ArrayList<SurveyConductBurglaryProperty>());

SurveyConductBurglaryProperty property = new SurveyConductBurglaryProperty();
property.setSurveyConductBurglaryDetails(details);

details.getSurveyConductBurglaryProperties().add(property);

session.save(details);
```